# Increasing number of threads leads to faster execution times?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my code below, I've read in previous earlier posts that some people experience faster running times with more threads as compared to lesser threads. However, based on my understanding of threads, I understand that due to context switching, it leads to an overall increase in time with a greater number of threads. However, when I run this piece of code, my execution time is strictly decreasing. Am I implementing this wrongly, or is this just because of my system. (I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MeanThread {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Bryan/Desktop/personal/Code/Java/Lab 2/src/input.txt"));
        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Double> temporalMeanArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Double temporalMean = 0.0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int number = s.nextInt();
            listOfValues.add(number);
        }
        // define number of threads
        // this way, you can pass number of threads as 
        // a second command line argument at runtime.
        int NumOfThread = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        // TODO: partition the array list into N subArrays, where N is the number of threads
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfSubArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(NumOfThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.size(); i += NumOfThread) {
            listOfSubArrays.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(listOfValues.subList(i, Math.min(i + NumOfThread, listOfValues.size()))));
        }
        // TODO: start recording time
        //Tip: you can't create big number of threads in the above way. So, create an array list of threads. 
        ArrayList<MeanMultiThread> threadList = new ArrayList<MeanMultiThread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfSubArrays.size(); i ++) {
            threadList.add(new MeanMultiThread(listOfSubArrays.get(i)));
        }
        // TODO: start each thread to execute your computeMean() function defined under the run() method
           //so that the N mean values can be computed. for example,
        int threadCounter = 1;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (MeanMultiThread mmt : threadList) {
            mmt.start();
        }

        for (MeanMultiThread mmt : threadList) {
            mmt.join();
            System.out.println("Temporal mean value of thread " + threadCounter + " is " + mmt.getMean());
            threadCounter ++;
            temporalMeanArray.add(mmt.getMean());
        }

        for (Double d : temporalMeanArray) {
            temporalMean += d;
        }
        Double globalMean = temporalMean/temporalMeanArray.size();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time is " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println("The global mean value is " + globalMean);

    }
}
//Extend the Thread class
class MeanMultiThread extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    private double mean;
    int counter = 0;
    MeanMultiThread(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        list = array;
    }
    public double getMean() {
        return mean;
    }
    public void run() {
        mean = computeMean(list);

    }
    private double computeMean(ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        double totalAmount = 0.0;
        for (int i : list2) {
            totalAmount += i;
        }
        return totalAmount/(list2.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: On a machine with multiple cores, the execution time should decrease with moderate amount of threads for long running tasks.

Comment: I tested it on a friend's computer with 4 cores, and the execution time increased at 2048 threads, as compared to 1 thread. Am I not getting something here?

Comment: With such a high amount of threads the context switching is affecting performance.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But why isn't it showing up on my code that it's affecting my performance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase the number of threads (`args[0]`) the actual number of threads used goes down. The reason is that you use `NumOfThread` as a bucket size for the sub arrays. As you increase the bucket size you have less buckets and hence less threads. The offending line is

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.size(); i += NumOfThread) {
```

together with

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfSubArrays.size(); i ++) {
```

Keep the bucket size constant regardless of the number of threads and then you'll get meaningful results. As your workload is entirely CPU-bound you won't get a meaningful speed-up as soon as you have more threads than the CPU can process concurrently.

Comment: When you say meaningful results, what do you mean? That the speed will get slower the higher number of threads?

Comment: Let's say you have 100 lines of input. If you set the number of threads to 1, you get 100 threads because the bucket size is 1 (input divided by number of threads). If you set the number of threads to 25, you get 4 threads. So you're changing two things at the same time: the amount of work and the amount of workers. I suppose you want to have a fixed amount of work with a variable number of workers.